# Access SQL server on different Amazon EC2 windows server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have the following scenario:

(a)Our old application was deployed to an amazon EC2 windows server with its own SQL server. We are using C# Entity Framework to access the database.

(b)Our new application will be deployed to an amazon EC2 windows server with its own SQL server. We are using C# Entity Framework to access the database.

(c) Our plan is to have both Applications running at the same time. If user want to upgrade to new application, we will convert the data from the old sql server to data in the sql server in the new EC2 windows server.
I need to figure out a way to access the old sql server from new EC2 windows servers with a configuration file in C# application. Is this possible?

Comment: That depends heavily on how you've configured the EC2 instance in the first place - a firewall would keep you connecting at all, for example.  Otherwise, this _should_ just be a standard "connect to remote server" issue.  Note that, if the only thing on the box is an SQL Server instance, it might be better to use an [RDS Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) (Amazon manages the server VM instead of you, mostly).

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to create the second EC2 instance in the local area network as the existing EC2 instance so that the SQL server  can be seen from each other.

Comment: Oh, I misread your question (I assumed the "new" version of your application split the database and application into two different VMs).  Yes, you should be able to do what you want (I don't happen to know how off hand), but long term I foresee scaling issues with this plan.  Among other things, if the application and the database were on - at minimum - separate machines, then if there were no schema changes you would just provide an updated application machine, and not even need to move data.

Comment: If I create the second EC2 windows server belonging to the same security group as the first EC2, is this going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work fine as far as the security group and firewall are open across the sql server and the EC2 instance. But the suggestion is to migrate data to single sql server and manage it via two applications on different EC2 as needed. 
It will resolve any problem of scaling in future or the data issues like redundancy, speed, etc.